# My web service based application occur lexical error

Tags: web-services, lexical

My web service based application occur lexical error. How to fix this? Please help me.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "operation")
public String operation(@WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password){ 

    String message = "";
    Connection myConObj = null;
    Statement myStatObj = null;
    PreparedStatement ps;  
    ResultSet myresObj = null;
    String query = "SELECT `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD` FROM HIRUNA.BANKLOGIN WHERE `USERNAME`=? AND `PASSWORD`=?";

    try{

        myConObj = mybank.getConnection();
        ps = myConObj.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

        result.next();
        message =  "Success!";
        result.close();
        myConObj.close();
        return message;

    }catch(SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return message;
    }
```

}

Here is the error..

> Severe:   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Lexical error at line 1,
>   column 8.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".

Comment: Use single quote ' instead of tick mark `

Answer (score 0):

Remove the back ticks:

```
String query = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM HIRUNA.BANKLOGIN WHERE USERNAME=? AND PASSWORD=?";
```